Problem Refreshing Session in NextJs Client Side
I am making a website with next-auth and nextjs where the user has different userTypes and based on that the navbar will be rendered and the userType is fetched from the session.
Now the issue is I have a form which updates the userType in the database but that also needs to be updated in the session to take effect
async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id as string;
        session.user.image = token.image as string | null;
        session.user.userType = token.userType as string;
    
        if (token.id) {
          try {
            const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
            const userDoc = await db.collection('users').findOne({ _id: token.id });
    
            if (userDoc) {
              session.user = {
                id: userDoc._id.toString(),
                name: userDoc.name,
                email: userDoc.email,
                image: userDoc.image,
                userType: userDoc.userType,
              };

              token.user = { ...session.user };
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching user data from database:', error);
          }
        }
      }
    
      return session;
    }

This code block is inside the callback function in authOptions in the backend to update the session in the backend but I am not able to update the session in the frontend so that the navbar reloads with new options unless I login and logout to fetch new session.
I tried to fetch the updated session from the backend and then
update the session in the frontend using
const { data: session, status, update } = useSession();
But I failed to do so.
